# Bootstrap table with fixed headers - Angular 5

Tags: css, angular5, css-tables

I have created a table with HTML and I want to display its header being fixed (scrolls would just affect to the body).

I have found a solution and it works almost as I want.

```
tbody {
  display:block;
  height:500px;
  overflow:auto;
}
thead, tbody tr {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  table-layout:fixed;/* even columns width , fix width of table too*/
}
thead {
  width: calc( 100% - 1em )/* scrollbar is average 1em/16px width, remove it from thead width */
}
table {
  width:400px;
}
```

The problem is that with the attribute `table-layout: fixed`, it fixes the the width of the column so my columns are not properly shown (they overlap):

[image]

How could I fix it?
I have already tried with the four possible values for [table-layout](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp)

Comment: use `table-layout:fixed;` only to the header `thead`

Comment: If I do that the width of every column in each line is different so it appears in a non beauty way

Comment: I tried to use your code and when i have long text it break line... maybe you have more style?

Comment: it does a break line just if you are using different words. If the words is, for example, 100 characters long, it will not do it

Comment: so use `td {word-wrap: break-word;}` OR `word-break: break-all;`

Comment: Thanks! This truly works

Comment: please mark my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `td {word-wrap: break-word;}`

```css
tbody {
  display:block;
  height:500px;
  overflow:auto;
}
thead, tbody tr {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  table-layout:fixed;/* even columns width , fix width of table too*/
}
td{
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
thead {
  width: calc( 100% - 1em )/* scrollbar is average 1em/16px width, remove it from thead width */
}
table {
  width:400px;
}
```

```html
<table class="a">
  <thead>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>AlfredsFutterkisteghrtrh</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: this is the answer

Comment: The problem is this solution, the table loses its responsiveness. Is it possible to maintain it? When I meant fixed headers I wanted to say non scrollable. But I do not want fixed sizes for a column.